# Search all worksheets in specific cloumn for specific text and paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm so new to vba that I have searched for this topic and though I have found similar questions I'm still having a hard time understanding the formulas so I hope someone can help.

I want to search Column B in all worksheets in my workbook for any cell that contains "Disc" within its text. I then want to copy and paste all the info from the row that it is found in, or if not the entire row, at the very least the info in columns B & C.

This is what I have tried so far but when I get to Select B:B, it is selecting the column on my "Discs" sheet instead of the worksheets it should be looping through.

```
Sub DiscFill()
 '
 '
 ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
   Dim DiscsSh As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim I As Integer

'add new sheet at the end'
Set DiscsSh = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
'rename it'
DiscsSh.Name = "Discs"

 'loop through all sheets'
 For Each sh In Worksheets
    'if sh is not Discs sheet, then'
     If sh.Name <> DiscsSh.Name Then


'Select Column Range and Search for Discs
Columns("B:B").Select

Cells.Find(What:="Component Discs", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

'Finds Row from Search and Adds 1 to start in the correct Row/sku#
startRow = Selection.Row + 1
'Go back to new sheet to start inputing data
Sheets("Discs").Select

'this tells you how far you can potentially go
For j = startRow To 999
        'if blank cell then the loop stops
        If Sheets(I).Cells(j, 3).Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    Else
                mat_num = Sheets(I).Cells(j, 3).Value
                TitleDescrip = Sheets(I).Cells(j, 2).Value
                Cells(counter, 1).Value = mat_num
                Cells(counter, 2).Value = TitleDescrip
                counter = counter + 1
        End If
Next j

    End If
Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, the reason for the Find "Component Discs" is because each worksheet has discs listed after that heading but searching column B:B for "Discs/" would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @SDension modified code hope this works

mention sheet obj.

```
  sh.Columns("B:B").Select

 sh.Cells.Find(What:="Component Discs", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
False, SearchFormat:=False).Select
```